# Category Selection is not getting saved in updating products

Tags: magento-1.8, category-products

When i'm trying to change category of my product, it does not getting saved, See below screenshot, after changing from `Test Category` to `Another Category` when click on Save it does not saved. Everything else (like attributes, short description, description, name, sku) changes does get saved. 
[image]

If i go to `Catelog >> Manage Categories` and then select `Another Category`, under `category products` if i select product and press Save - it does get saved.

please guide me if anyone came across this situation

Comment: Do you have any custom extensions installed that might affect the catalog?

Comment: Yes, we have 'Store Manager for Magento' http://emagicone.com/products/solutions-for-magento-commerce/ But its desktop software not extension in magento

Comment: You can try to debug by following the steps explained in here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/428/146

Comment: I have try to debug, but not able to find solution yet..! also have removed all extensions

Answer (score 1):

Finally got my answer,

I had an attribute with identifier `product_categories`, I have just deleted that attribute and now category selection does get saved.

I don't know why magento behave like this but it worked for me

Comment: sure @Marius, just for my knowledge, do you idea why that attribute was causing issue?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea.

Comment: Speculation: That should not be an attribute, in EAV. The value of product_categories is dynamically generated by code to a comma separated list of categories a product belongs to. Having that (incorrectly) as an EAV attribute most likely broke that dynamic asignment/replaced the correct values with null